# Am I the first to review questions in close votes review queue because of Marshal badge?

Tags: discussion, review, badges, vote-to-close

I noticed that I am more than 70% of time the first one to review questions in the close votes review queue (CVRQ) on SO. I don't think it was because of reputation, since there was no good number at the time. Around that time I received the Marshal badge. Before that I was practically never the first to review. Is this the reason I'm now the first one?

Some more information: I usually review [javascript] or completely without filter and skip 5%-20% of the questions. **This changed in the time from Aug 29 to Sep 7.** The time span is so large because I didn't review anything in this time.

Why did it change? Does it change anything? I would think that if I vote to *Leave open* as the first reviewer so that the question is moved to the back of the queue, but this doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: What does the Marshal badge have to do with reviewing? You raised 500 helpful flags, but that doesn't say anything about you being first to raise a flag.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't see another reason why this would change.

Comment: *Or* it could be that the queue has changed to prioritise new posts added. That way everyone is presented fresh unreviewed posts first..

Comment: @MartijnPieters [badge was awarded](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal?userid=1816580) on Aug 29, [recent features list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal?userid=1816580) shows nothing related around that date. FWIW I am most often 3rd-5th to review, but this may be because of my habits ([filtering](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0pyUG.png) too-broad and [skipping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232140/165773) everything but blatantly bad stuff and audits)

Comment: @gnat: I still fail to see any correlation here. Just because the OP managed to accumulate 500 helpful flags over time?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I also find such a correlation hard to believe. More likely there was some unannounced change in [sort order](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773) or some substantial change in habits of active reviewers, or in the distribution of questions in the queue. Of changes I noticed recently, it sits mostly under 10K, and there seem to be more older questions in there than month or 2 or 3 ago. This stuff is [fuzzy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601)...

Comment: @gnat: exactly; I was alluding to the fuzzing post, mostly. I was mostly puzzled as to how the OP drew the correlation here.

Comment: In other words, this is asking what the logic is that decides the question you see in the CVRC?

Comment: it would help to understand things if you [edit] the question to describe your filtering options and skipping habits and whether you changed them at around end August - beginning of September

Comment: @ben Yes, this would be the general question. I'm sure there exists already a post which answers this, but I didn't find it. Right, now I'm more interested in the change.